# When Mapping by Id. Who is the owner of the Id

Tags: java, oop, architecture, software-design

Let say we have a `Person` with an `Id: String, name: String`.
Then, In an other class, we have `Map<String, Person>` that holds the persons by Id.
My Question Is should the person hold that Id. Or now the owner of the Id is the Map itself.
PS: Note using map for performance reasons, but because it makes sens for modeling.

Comment: I was in a hurry to write it, my bad :). By own an Id I mean who is responsible for It. In simple words, If I have a Map<PersonId, Person> should the person still hold the PersonId?

Comment: I don't know why you said the database, I didn't talk about It. and In any case the database doesn't own the data, It only stores them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Person is an entity, it has an Id, so yes, it should hold it.

It doesn't make sense to me to model that again by a Map in a different class, I would have to understand your model better to be able to comment on that.  Unless PersonId is *not* the identity element of the Person model.  If it were in fact a different entity, then Person should have it's own Id, and PersonId would have a different, separate Id...  Regardless, the model is pretty incomplete, and it's really hard to make recommendations.

If it is just the obvious case, and PersonId is the Id of the Person, then your Map is just an index, which is also ok, but isn't really part of the Model.

Comment: Makes sens. So I think a conclusion, it depends on the use case.